# use different color scales in xarray faceted imshow

Tags: python-xarray

If I have a `DataArray` that I plot with faceted subplots:

```
da = xr.tutorial.scatter_example_dataset().A.isel(z=1)
da.plot(x='x', y='y', col='w')
```

[image]

`xarray` nicely chooses the same color bar for all the panels. But this doesn't work if one panel has very different scales that the others:

```
da[:,:,2] += 5
da.plot(x='x', y='y', col='w')
```

[image]

Can I have xarray choose `clim` separately for each panel?

Comment: Related issue at https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1387. May need to do manually using matplotlib subplot for now.